# Cannot download videos on Ubuntu 12.04 using youtube-dl

Tags: 12.04, video, flash, youtube

I wanted to download this particular video of David Archuleta - Crush and i cannot seem to download it. I tried updating , reinstalling the application using the terminal but still cannot download the video.

The Problem with it is I cannot download it from any Video Service like Vimeo or Youtube.
I tried with Youtube, also got the available formats but failed to download the video. Here's the link of the [Video](http://vimeo.com/1938955)

PLease someone tell me if its the Video problem or the Application Problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [link](http://vimeo.com/1938955) you have provided there is the download button so you need not use any command.

To download from youtube, first install `youtube-dl`

```
$sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

To download video

```
$youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6J1-eYBbspA
```

**Note:**  Latest version of `youtube-dl` can be found [here](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl)

or update it using

```
$sudo youtube-dl -U
```

Comment: I'm more comfortable in the Command version downloads than the Gui. its just personal.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube-dl is known to hav some serious problems, and i tried it out and found them out for myself. It totally failed to work with me

I recommend [minitube](http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube), which does not need any complicated command based processes. You just search the video you want to download, and then download it right away...with a bonus of watching other videos on youtube while you wait for your download to finish..

[image]

You can also [download it from Ubuntu Software Center](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/minitube/).

As another alternative, you can run an application called windows app called [YTD](http://download.cnet.com/YTD-Video-Downloader/3000-2071_4-10647340.html) (YoutubeVideo Downloader), inside [wine](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu) or [crossover](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/)...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I see.

[image: Screenshot of the linked video in question]

When I click the [Video Link](http://vimeo.com/1938955) you have posted on your question.

When I click the on "↓ Download" It opens a small panel where get to select a download link. When I click it, it downloads the video in .flv format.